# Good ways to visualize a word-like document

Tags: visualization, data-mining, lexical-analysis

What are some good ways to visualize a word-like document?

Edit:
It doesn't have to be a .doc, it could be a text file or blog post...

Comment: As a series of words on a page?  More details please.

Comment: Do you want to see layout and non-printing markup? Go to menu View -> Print Layout. Or you can find the button on the Standard Toolbar that shows/hides characters like Space, Paragraph, Tab,...

Answer (score 1):

[Word cloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_cloud) is a nice way to visualize word frequency

**EDIT:** Check out the text visualization section in [IBM Many Eyes](http://manyeyes.alphaworks.ibm.com/manyeyes/page/Visualization_Options.html)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the content it have! I can see (from data-mining perspective)

- a word freq histogram
- a chart for showing document chapters against total number of word in that section
- charts for any tabular data. (i think tables can be identified with some pattern)